# gatsby-image: setup image processing pipeline

Tags: gatsby

I'm working on the Gatsby.js website and would like to setup images pre-processing with gatsby-image and gatsby-plugin-sharp.
The problem is that the images I use have different aspect rates and different dimensions. What I'm trying to achive is square fluid thumbnails generated automatically. So far I managed to use `fluid` in my GraphQL queries, but unfortunately it crops the image. I also tried `fit` parameter form [gatsby-plugin-sharp](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-sharp/#parameters-2) doc but it looks like it was removed some time ago:

```
image {
  relativePath
  childImageSharp {
    fluid(maxWidth: 320, maxHeight: 320, cropFocus: CENTER) {
      ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
    }
  }
}
```

The result:
[image]
Expected result:
[image]

The source image is square - 2480x2480 px.

So i wonder if there is a way to setup multiple steps of the image processing - resize first to 2x or 3x of needed dimension, and make it fluid after that?

My dependencies from `package.json` just in case:

```
"gatsby": "^2.2.8",
"gatsby-image": "^2.0.41",
"gatsby-paginate": "^1.0.17",
"gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager": "^2.0.10",
"gatsby-plugin-layout": "^1.0.13",
"gatsby-plugin-less": "^2.0.12",
"gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.0.24",
"gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms": "^3.0.16",
"gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms-paths": "^1.2.1",
"gatsby-plugin-offline": "^2.0.25",
"gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.0.10",
"gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.0.32",
"gatsby-remark-images": "^3.0.10",
"gatsby-remark-relative-images": "^0.2.2",
"gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.0.28",
"gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.3.8",
```

Comment: Wrong ImageSharp. Please read tag descriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue:

1. `fit` was added in `gatsby-plugin-sharp@2.0.34` and I was using
   `2.0.32`. So `npm update` helped with it.
2. I was wrong that my source image is square. It's vertical and that's why the result image is cropped.

So that eliminates the need of multiple steps processing for my thumbnails.